# Azure Devops development: invoke pipeline task from typescript code

Tags: typescript, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I want to develop a custom task that is going to execute some custom test.
These custom test generate jUnit style test result.

Within the code of my custom task I would like to invoke the official task called “Publish Test Results” (PublishTestResults@2 in the yml file).
Is it possible to invoke a pipeline task from the Typescript code of another task?

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. You would need to have your custom task run the test and save the results in the suitable format. After that have the PublishTestResults@2 configure to look for the result files you've created

Comment: Hi @DavidCox88 thankyou for the replay. I understand that you mean ti use the task separately in the pipeline. I know this Is possibile, but I want only one task in my pipeline \n  This because I want to male the pipeline fail if one test fails. If I do this then the publishtestresult won't be executed

Comment: it's not possible to do this in a single task. However, you can add "condition:always()" to the publish test results task. This ensure the test results are always published, even if the pipeline fails

Comment: Hi @DavidCox88 I can use this solution. Thankyou very much. Gianluca

Comment: @DavidCox88 do you maybe know this one as well?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73543644/azure-version-number-must-increase-each-time-an-extension-is-published